# Apple Transporter verification strange errors

Tags: ios, xcode, itmstransporter

When trying to verify an ios app using Transporter before sending to store, it spits out 8 strange errors/issues that I have no idea where to start from

[image]

And in text:

```
(&(osgi.native.osname~=Linux)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64))

(&(package=com.apple.its.epubcheck)(version>=4.4.0)(!(version>=5.0.0)))

(&(|(arch~=arm64)(arch~=arm64e))(rosetta=false))

A downloaded software component is corrupted and will not be used. https://contentdelivery.itunes.apple.com/transporter/repositories/j2se8/2.1.0/bundles/com.apple.its.epubcheck-runner-4.4.1.jar

could not find the service with interface (com.apple.transporter.osgi.TransporterService)

unsatisfied requirement: com.apple.transporter.aspera-linux-x64

unsatisfied requirement: com.apple.transporter.aspera-macos-arm64

unsatisfied requirement: com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
cd ~
mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/
```